# Defining Probability Distribution with parameters

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions

I have a family of probability distributions, indexed by elements in $\mathcal I =\mathbb N \times [0,1] \times [0,1]$. For each $(A,B,C) \in \mathcal I$ I know how to define the corresponding distribution $\mathcal D_{A,B,C}$.

```
dist := 
   ProbabilityDistribution[
   PDF[BinomialDistribution[A, y*B + (1 - y)*0.5], x]   
   PDF[BernoulliDistribution[C], y], 
   {x, 0, A, 1}, 
   {y, 0, A, 1}];
```

What I want is to define a probability distribution with parameters, so that fixing parameters `n,p,q` will yield $\mathcal D_{A,B,C}$.

I have tried the obvious, e.g.

```
dist[n_,p_,q_] := 
   ProbabilityDistribution[
   PDF[BinomialDistribution[n, y*p + (1 - y)*0.5], x]   
   PDF[BernoulliDistribution[q], y], 
   {x, 0, n, 1}, 
   {y, 0, n, 1}];
```

But I get an error message of the form `SetDelayed::write: Tag ProbabilityDistribution in`...`is Protected.`

I'm thinking there's some simple solution I don't know about (I'm new to Mathematica). I have also tried this (I don't know whether it amounts to the same thing):

```
dist[n_, p_, q_] := 
 ProbabilityDistribution[
 PDF[BinomialDistribution[i, y*j + (1 - y)*0.5], x] 
 PDF[BernoulliDistribution[k], y], 
 {x, 0, i, 1}, 
 {y, 0, i, 1}] /. {i -> n, j -> p, k -> q};
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: The lines you say have `SetDelayed::write` message, they run fine for me on MMA 10.2…

Comment: Mathematica will evaluate `dist` before `dist[...]`, so the `SetDelayed` error is because your `dist[n_,p_,q_] := ...` statement is becoming `ProbabilityDistribution[...][n_,p_,q_] := ...` when evaluated. Does it work if you `ClearAll[dist]` first?

Comment: Have you looked at `ProductDistribution[]`?

Comment: @mfvonh, you are correct. Rookie mistake, I suppose!

Comment: Not sure what the protocol is, now. Should I just delete the question? There are no answers I can accept, so...

Comment: You could answer your own question, y'know…

Comment: Thank you for this question! I had the same doubt. It is always nice to realise that someone already asked it.

I think that the documentation on this subject in Mathematica (version 11.1) could still be improved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just needed to do `ClearAll[dist]` first, as mfvonh pointed out in the comments.

Comment: Do you mean `ClearAll[dist]` (capitalization)?

Comment: Yes, thank you.